# Mockito mocks not being called - ArgumentCaptor being ignored

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockito

I want to test the following code, on a `UserServiceImplV1` class:

```java
    @Override
    public void updateUserPassword(VerificationCodeDTO code, String newPassword) {
        if(verificationCodeService.isValid(code)) {
            UserDTOV1 user = userService.findByEmail(code.getEmail());
            user.setPassword(newPassword);
            userService.save(user);
            verificationCodeService.delete(code.getEmail());
        } else {
            throw new ValidationException("Código de usuário inválido");
        }
    }
```

So I wrote the following test:

```java
@Test
    public void updatesUserPasswordAndDeletesToken() {
        UserDTOV1 userDTO = new UserDTOV1("John", "a@mail.com", "123", UserType.PESSOAFISICA, "oldPassword");
        VerificationCodeDTO verificationCodeDTO = new VerificationCodeDTO("abcd", userDTO.getEmail());

        when(verificationCodeService.isValid(any())).thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE);
        when(userService.findByEmail("a@mail.com")).thenReturn(userDTO);
        when(userService.save(any(UserDTOV1.class))).thenAnswer(invocation -> invocation.getArgument(0));
        ArgumentCaptor<UserDTOV1> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(UserDTOV1.class);
        verify(userService, times(1)).save(captor.capture());
        UserDTOV1 actual = captor.getValue();

        authService.updateUserPassword(verificationCodeDTO, "newPassword");
        Assert.assertEquals("newPassword", actual.getPassword());
        verify(verificationCodeService, times(1)).delete(anyString());
    }
```

And I get the following error:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
userService.save(<Capturing argument>);
-> at (...).updatesUserPasswordAndDeletesToken(AuthServiceImplV1Test.java:45)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I've tried capturing arguments in a lot of ways, like

```java
verify(userService, times(1)).save(argThat(argument -> argument.getPassword().equals("newPasword")));
```

But the error is the same, almost as if my mocks weren't being applied. I'm creating them, though, and all the other tests in this file work:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AuthServiceImplV1Test {
    @Mock
    private UserServiceImplV1 userService;

    @Mock
    private VerificationCodeServiceImplV1 verificationCodeService;

    @InjectMocks
    private AuthServiceImplV1 authService;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're verifying that the mock has been called *before* calling the method under test. So at that point, the mock hasn't been called yet.